# Remove values in rows, Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, rows

im trying to "remove" some rows. This is my code

```
popcoun = census_df.copy()
popcoun = popcoun[popcoun['SUMLEV'] == 50]
popcoun = popcoun[['STNAME','CTYNAME','CENSUS2010POP']]
popcoun = popcoun.set_index(['STNAME','CTYNAME'])
popcoun = popcoun.sort_values(by = ['STNAME','CENSUS2010POP'],ascending = False)
```

[Visualice table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maaSk.png)

In the previous image link, you can observe that the information is sorted, so, for example, in the Wioming index, i only want the first three rows of the CENSUS2010POP (which are the highest values in that state), and also for the other states i have.
Thank you, i hope somebody help me

Comment: Can you mention what have you tried in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this -

```
popcoun = popcoun.groupby(['STNAME']).head(3)
```

This should work as long as the rows are sorted for each group as you have mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just select the top 3 rows of the table, you can do

```
df.iloc[:4]
```

For each state, you can iterate over `df["state"].unique()` and do `df.loc[df.state == state][:4]`

Sorry if I misunderstood. Does this help?

Comment: He needs top 3 rows from each group, not just the top 3 rows from the whole table.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal what I suggested underneath the df.iloc[:4] gives the top 3 rows from each group of states...

Comment: That just returns a list of dataframes for each state group. Not the output that the guy wants.

Comment: I really apreciate the time guys <3 
At first i tried to iterate as you suggested @GLaw1300, but i could not implemented it, does not know how to do it jaja

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of sorting... this would work with `.groupby` and `.nlargest`

```
popcoun = popcoun.groupby(['STNAME']).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3, 'CENSUS2010POP'))[['CITYNAME', 'CENSUS2010POP']]
```